# python pandas dataframe keep only 0-9,a-b and spaces

Tags: pandas, text

I have a pandas dataframe and it has a column of text data. Currently i am using below code to get rid everything other than a-z and 0-9. But this also gets rid of spaces between words. How could i preserve spacing between words?

```
abc_file_found['pdf_text'] =abc_file_found['pdf_text'].str.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]', '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
abc_file_found['pdf_text'] =abc_file_found['pdf_text'].str.replace('[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]', ' ')
```

Comment: it keeps `___`/dashes

Comment: Sorry my bad. I've updated the expression. This one should work. By nature, '\w' doesn't remove the underscore.